# Redshift data mirroring / mocking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have a requirement to mirror data from one environment to other in AWS redshift. Would that be possible using snapshots or is there any other way possible?

The mirroring/ replication of data is to test a proof of concept by our vendor and this is between two clusters residing in the same region. The lag part we are not sure and what would be the best approach here, please suggest.

It is essentially from prod to test environment. Regarding one directional, did u meant the data flow. Please suggest any best practices that we can look for in this scenario.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and provide more details about what you mean by "mirror data from one environment to other in AWS redshift"? Do you mean between two Redshift clusters? Are the clusters in the same region? Can you provide more information as to WHY you wish to do this (eg dev/test/prod), since it might influence the answer. How much lag is permitted between the mirrors -- seconds, or is one update per day sufficient? Is it one-directional, or two-directional? Etc.

Comment: can you update both in parallel? then run regular consistency checks?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is to replicate an Amazon Redshift production cluster to another Amazon Redshift cluster that will be used for testing.

Since test systems rarely need up-to-date production data, such replication would typically be done **weekly** or, if automated, **daily**.

It is also best-practice to **cleanse the data** being replicated to test systems to remove sensitive customer information. This could be done by running a script that clears or obfuscates particular columns (eg credit card numbers).

If you are happy with completely deleting the test system every time it is reloaded from production, the easiest way to replicate would be:

- **Delete** the old Test cluster
- **Take a snapshot** of the production system
- **Launch a new cluster** from the snapshot
- Run any **cleanup scripts** against the Test system

The new cluster would initially need to be the same size as the original cluster (eg if production is 3-node, then the new cluster would be 3-node), but you can later resize the test system if you wish to reduce costs.

These steps can easily be **automated in a script** that uses the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). You could, for example, run it each night so that there is a fresh Test system available each day.

**Update: Restoring only a portion of the cluster**

Based upon the comment below, it appears that you are using a Redshift cluster for both Dev and Test, as different databases within the cluster.

In this situation, you could use the [Restore Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html#working-with-snapshot-restore-table-from-snapshot) functionality:

- Delete all tables in the Test database
- Restore each table individually from the snapshot

This would involve more steps and would not be advisable. It might be simpler to use a separate cluster for Test, so that it can be totally deleted and repopulated.

Comment: Thanks John , for your valuable comments. I will go ahead with this approach . And a cleansing would be surely needed I guess :)

Comment: Hi john, Also if we have two DB instances in a single cluster and we go ahead with this approach, when the cluster gets deleted ( having both dev and test dbs) it takes down dev also along with it . Can we restrict the change only to test environment alone. Is there a way around for this.

Comment: Thanks John once again, this was quite an information.

Comment: Hi John  had a curious query on the restore table functionality. Can we do on a schema level mirroring. say we have a schema in prod can we reproduce the same schema in test db instance under a new name like we do for RDS databases. This would reduce the overall efforts. Please let me know ur thoughts

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with schema-level mirroring. The answer is... if PostgreSQL can do it, then you can do it.